# mysql index: Почему при удалении и создании такого же индекса запрос может работать медленне?

Tags: mysql

`mysql` версия 5.5.55-0 `Ubuntu-14.04.1`

Используется `innodb`

**вчера:** загрузил дамп БД, запрос без индекса выполнялся 10 секунд, создал индекс - запрос с индексом выполнялся 4 секунды

**сегодня:** загрузил такой же дамп БД как и вчера, запрос без индекса выполняется 10 секунд, создал такой же индекс как и вчера - **запрос с индексом выполняется 12 секунд**

в чем может быть проблема?

`EXPLAIN` показывает что индекс используется

Пробовал отключать все программы которые жрут много памяти (свободно стало 6000 МБ) в итоге не в этом проблема

Comment: Использование индекса может как ускорять так и замедлять запрос. надо внимательно рассматривать сам запрос, план выполнения и при этом анализировать данные по которым он работает. например, поиск 10 записей по индексу из 1000 - это гораздо быстрее чем, тот же поиск без индекса, а вот получение 500 записей из 1000 по индексу медленнее, чем перебором таблицы без использования индекса.

Comment: @Mike всеравно не понятно, почему при таких же действиях как и вчера, запрос выполняется с индексом медленней,

Comment: @Mike а удаление индекса и создание заново, только увеличивает время выборки

Comment: т.е. вы залили дамп из того же самого файла и перед тем как его залить явно удалили таблицу ? и индекс и вчера и сегодня создавали уже после заливки всех данных ? вообще в innodb все данные лежат в одном большом файле и при повторном залитии данные могут лечь в другие блоки и индекс может физически на диске оказаться дальше и головкам придется бегать дальше, что конечно скажется на скорости выборки. правда 4 и 12 секунд какая то слишком большая разница ...

Comment: @Mike Да, удалил БД, залил новый дамп, создал индекс, спасибо за подсказку сейчас попробую тогда методом научного тыка поудалять БД и позаливать новую=)

Comment: @Mike не, не получится метод научного тыка =) т.к. используется SSD